# Angular with Tailwind and SASS - Can't resolve path to asset

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

When running (ng serve) my Angular 15 APP, it runs with no issues

I can see the updated page and all assets load correctly

When making changes and saving, the APP fails to compile

```
./src/styles.sass - Error: Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
D:\Congressa\ceteval\src\styles.sass:4:0: Can't resolve '../../assets/img/gallery/landing.jpg' in 'D:\Congressa\ceteval\src'
```

Contents of the .sass file:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@tailwind base
@tailwind components
@tailwind utilities
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
    "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin')
  ],
}
```

I have to stop the App, and re-run it for it to work properly again

And, the cherry on top, i have more assets on the same file, but I get no error from those

```
<div class="h-screen bg-[url('../../assets/img/gallery/landing.jpg')]">
<img class="w-24 h-24 md:w-48 md:h-auto md:rounded-xl object-cover rounded-full mx-auto" src="../../assets/img/gallery/juango.png" alt="" width="384" height="512">
```

I'm half expecting for it to be a misconfiguration, so if I have to recreate the project I'm willing to, but it feels like I'm just missing something pretty obvious

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, when setting an image as a class in tailwind, it fails, not sure if its a bug, if it only fails because i'm using angular or sass
Anyway, I fixed it by changing it to:

```
<div class="mb-10 relative overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-cover bg-no-repeat p-12 text-center h-screen" style="background-image: url('../../assets img/gallery/landing.jpg');"></div>
```

I basically set it as background-image in the style property, that got rid of the issue

Would still love if someone gave an explanation as to why it works like this

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use relative path , use exact root path for asset
2. check your asset folder in the file angular.json
3. Probably some cache issue, restart the server and clean the cache